# Using Window.resize and media queries to move a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRlvh.jpg) I am using the window resize function to check the width of my page, if it's below 891, I fire the function to move my #formWrapper div to #formbottom on the page, the media query is set to max width 891 to change the formWrapper to float left, and have a max-width of 100%.  Everything is almost working properly but there is a slight jump, when the browser reaches 891px, it seems like the media query and the JS function are slightly off?

You can see this by resizing the browser window.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {

      if ($(window).width() < 891) {
        $("#formWrapper").detach().appendTo('#formbottom');

      } else {
        if ($(window).width() > 891) {
          $("#formWrapper").detach().appendTo('#formtop');
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */


/* Reset */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* remember to define focus styles! */

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: "" "";
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* LANDING PAGE */

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 38px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}


/* landing page masthead */

#mastheadBar {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FDA929;
}

#mastheadImage {
  max-width: 1520px;
  background-image: url(https://pages.infor.com/rs/227-UHD-858/images/hero.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  margin: auto;
}

.logoWrapper {
  max-width: 310px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
}

.LogoWrapperText {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 21px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: #FFF;
  max-width: 50.2128%;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}


/* landing page main content */

#mainContent {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainContent p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #737373;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

#mainContent li {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0 0 8px 10px;
}

#mainContent ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#mainContentLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 57.4468085106383%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#mainContentLeftWrap {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

#mainContentRight {
  float: right;
  width: 31.91489361702128%;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

#mainContentRight img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #737373;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#footerWrapper {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 22px 50px 22px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* form page */

#formWrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 36.1702%;
}

#formWrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content-wrapperForm {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 38px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContentWrap {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#mainContentWrap p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #737373;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

#mainContentWrap li {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0 0 8px 10px;
}

#mainContentWrap ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.formIntro {
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
}

.formIntroCta {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.formIntroReq {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.formIntroImg {
  float: right;
  width: 70px;
}

.formIntroImg img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* form */


/* form wrapper */

.mktoForm {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}


/* remove form wrapper padding mobile */

.mktoMobileShow .mktoForm,
.mktoForm * {
  padding: 0 !important;
}


/* remove form wrapper padding */

.mktoForm,
.mktoForm * {
  padding: 0 !important;
}


/* form column holding field and label */

.mktoForm .mktoFormCol {
  float: left;
  min-height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
}


/* form column wrapper */

.mktoForm .mktoFieldWrap {
  float: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}


/* form column left padding - set to zero to make columns flush to left */

.mktoForm .mktoOffset {
  float: left;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 0 !important;
}


/* Non-required Label */

.mktoForm .mktoLabel {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 7px !important;
  width: auto !important;
}


/* Required field label */

.mktoForm .mktoRequiredField label.mktoLabel {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}


/* Asterix appearance */

.mktoForm .mktoAsterix {
  color: #bf0000;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}


/* Asterix position */

.mktoForm.mktoLayoutAbove .mktoRequiredField .mktoAsterix {
  float: right !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* Field formating */

.mktoForm input[type="text"],
.mktoForm input[type="url"],
.mktoForm input[type="email"],
.mktoForm input[type="tel"],
.mktoForm input[type="number"],
.mktoForm input[type="date"],
.mktoForm textarea.mktoField,
.mktoForm select.mktoField {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9 !important;
  padding: 10px 12px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}


/* Button row container */

.mktoButtonRow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Button style */

.mktoForm button.mktoButton {
  background-color: #fc6621;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding: 12px !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  margin-left: 0;
}


/* Reset for form items to be flush left */

.mktoForm div,
.mktoForm span,
.mktoForm label,
.mktoForm p {
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Field text formating */

.mktoForm .mktoField {
  color: #666666;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  line-height: 19px;
}


/* Comment field formating */

.mktoForm.mktoLayoutAbove textarea.mktoField {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}


/* Float check and radio button right */

.mktoRadioList {
  width: auto !important;
  float: left !important;
  clear: none !important;
}


/* Remove left padding from Radio and Checkbox */

.mktoForm .mktoRadioList,
.mktoForm .mktoCheckboxList {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.mktoForm select.mktoField::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.mktoForm select.mktoField {
  background: url(http://na-ab22.marketo.com/rs/625-VIS-608/images/input_icon_selector.png) no-repeat right;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-position-x: 97%;
}


/* Checkbox formating */

.mktoCheckboxList input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.mktoCheckboxList input,
.mktoCheckboxList label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mktoCheckboxList label {
  position: relative;
}


/* Edit the properties below to change the colors of the un-checked checkbox */

.mktoCheckboxList input+label:before {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25px;
}


/* Edit the properties below to change the colors of the checked checkbox */

.mktoCheckboxList input:checked+label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  background: #56CFD2;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #3eb9bc;
}

body .mktoForm .mktoCheckboxList>label {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/* Checkbox and Radio formating */

.mktoRadioList input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.mktoRadioList input,
.mktoRadioList label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mktoRadioList label {
  position: relative;
}


/* Edit the properties below to change the colors of the un-checked radio button */

.mktoRadioList input+label:before {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25px;
  ;
}

.mktoRadioList input+label:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* Edit the properties below to change the colors of the checked radio button */

.mktoRadioList input:checked+label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: #bbb;
}

.mktoRadioList input:focus+label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* focus style */
}


/* Radio button label padding */

body .mktoForm .mktoRadioList>label {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}


/* Radio button wrapper padding */

.mktoForm.mktoLayoutAbove .mktoRadioList {
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}


/* Error Message */

.mktoForm .mktoError {
  color: #666666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* Error Message arrow */

.mktoForm .mktoError .mktoErrorArrow {
  background-color: #666666 !important;
  border-top-color: #666666 !important;
  border-right-color: #666666 !important;
  border-bottom-color: #666666 !important;
  border-left-color: #666666 !important;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}


/* Error Message box */

.mktoForm .mktoError .mktoErrorMsg {
  background-color: #666666 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #666666 !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 5px !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  margin-top: 7px !important;
}


/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media all and (max-width:891px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 49px;
    color: #FFF;
    max-width: 745px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
  }
  .content-wrapperForm {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #mainContentLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #formWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:320px) {
  #mastheadImage {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .logoWrapper {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
  }
  #footerWrapper {
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 22px 30px 22px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Other Meta Tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="LP-Standard-Form-2017-2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>${page-title}</title>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- container -->
  <div id="container">
    <!-- masthead -->
    <div id="mastheadBar">
      <div id="mastheadImage">
        <div class="content-wrapperForm">
          <div id="formtop">
            <div id="formWrapper">
              <div class="formIntro">
                <div class="formIntroCta">Please fill in the form below.</div>
                <div class="formIntroReq">Fields marked with a <span style="color: #fc6621">*</span> are required.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="formIntroImg"></div>
              <div class="mktoForm" id="DKform1" mktoName="Form"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="logoWrapper">
            <div class="LogoWrapperText">${logo-text}</div>
          </div>
          <h1>${page-title}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/masthead -->
    <!--main content-->
    <div id="mainContentWrap">
      <div class="content-wrapperForm">
        <div id="mainContentLeft">
          <div id="mainContentLeftWrap" class="mktoText" mktoName="Main Body Text">
            <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
              erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
            <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
              <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
              <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>

            </ul>
            <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
              erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
            <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
              <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
              <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
              erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
            <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
              <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
              <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Aenean sed orci efficitur, convallis arcu sit amet, consequat dolor. Vestibulum vestibulum nisl quis mattis rhoncus. Cras ut imperdiet leo. Phasellus luctus mauris lectus, quis semper dui dignissim at. Donec lacinia, turpis ac hendrerit dictum,
              erat nisl iaculis lacus, eu ultrices libero nisi eu sapien. Praesent id congue elit, sed rutrum lorem. Duis quis nisi elit. Pellentesque nec cursus leo.</p>
            <p>Vivamus quis ex pellentesque, pharetra elit eget, molestie arcu:</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Integer ornare velit metus, sit amet tincidunt neque</li>
              <li>luctus vitae. Suspendisse vulputate cursus</li>
              <li>scelerisque. Sed ac lectus eget nisi facilisis</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="formbottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!--/main content-->
  <!--footer-->

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footerWrapper">© Copyright
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
      </script> Infor. All rights reserved.</div>
  </div>
  <!--/footer-->

  </div>
  <!--/container -->





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the "slight jump" in a little more detail?  Also, does this happen in any particular browser over another?

Comment: Rather than creating your own listener for change of media query interval, consider using a tiny (8k), highly tested, production ready library, called [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) specialised in this. Has a pretty nice api covering all possible media queries needs. My praise for it doesn't come from being affiliated in any way, just a long time user. It never fails, it never had a compatibility problem with anything and works cross-browser. You'll than be able to debug if the jump is caused by the listener or by what change you trigger.

Comment: Sure.  Above 891px the form is placed in a div near the top of the page, what want to do is when the browser resizes to below 891px the form code moves to another div so i can float it below the pages body copy for mobile view.  However it looks like i can't match the media query of max width 891px to the JS code. So the formWrapper moves to the appropriate section of the code, however the media query is not firing, so it floating right to the body copy.  I will add a screen shot so you can see.

Comment: I'm showing the middle image occurring between roughly 892 to 907 pixels instead of exactly at 891, otherwise I would check in the script where it's greater than 891 and less than 891 but with nothing at 891, just to start.

Comment: Andrei Gheorghiu this worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't change the code, only added transition property to #fromWrapper.

Please find the answer.
[Updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly578hgu/1/)

```
#formWrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: This did not help, it's still not firing correctly.  Thank you for trying.